# Why the French, but the Greeks?

Tags: grammatical-number, demonyms

Why do we say

> ***the French***

to refer to the French people collectively, while we say

> ***the Greeks, the Russians, the Jews***?

Why ***the Chinese***, but ***the Tibetans*** and ***the Germans***? Why are some such nouns countable plurals?

We also say the "Soviets".

Comment: If you really think there is an answer to this sort of "why question" (vowel changes perhaps), then I advise you 1. To remove the "don't get me started sentence" because that flags this as a [rant](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) rather than a question. 2. Express the problem clearly. It would seem you are talking about the reltation between the English word for the name of a country and its inhabitants. In this case leave the Jews out of it and write China rather than the first Chinese. Otherwise I can see the question getting closed quite soon.

Comment: You can certainly employ "Chinese" or "Japanese" as plural nouns - "There were two Chinese and three Japanese in the bar". And there are always "Spaniards".

Comment: Yes, but Spanish works as a plural too. The sentence the old man the boat come to mind.

Comment: David, feel free to edit the question. I thought the peripherally relevant other examples give perspective and the question

Comment: "ancient Greeks".  Why the reference to ancient Greeks?  Greece today has exactly the same demonym, just without the word "ancient"...

Comment: Fair point which I thought about I just seldom have had occasion to speak of contemporary Greeks.

Comment: It's your question — it doesn't particularly interest me — so it's your job to sort it out if you don't want it closed. (And I've only just seen your comment because you left out the @ which would have alerted me to it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only way this question can be answered is by reference to etymology.

Clearly many of the peoples neighbouring the English have demonyms in "-ish" or "-ch".  The words "French", "Welsh", "Scottish", "Danish", "Irish" all go back to Old English (although most of them were originally adjectives, and "Irish" as a noun isn't attested until Middle English).  Even so, of course, "Danish" coexisted with "Dane", and "Scottish" with "Scot", and this is true to this day: we can refer to "the Danish" (pl.), "Danes" (pl.) or "Dane" (sg.).

"Spanish" is first attested in Middle English, according to the OED, although Old English had the word "speonisc" with the same meaning, but it seems this is seen as a different word on the grounds that the English name for "Spain" has been remodelled after the Anglo-Norman.

"Greek" was an early borrowing from Latin into Germanic (and hence Old English).  The OED tells us:

> The Old English *Crécas* plural, corresponds to Old High German *Chrêch* , *Chriech* (Middle High German *Kriech* ), Gothic Krêks < *Krêko-z , an early Germanic adoption of Latin *Graecus* , plural *Graecī* (see below), the name applied by the Romans to the people called by themselves *Ἕλληνες* . The substitution of k for g is commonly accounted for by the supposition that the Germanic initial g , when the word was adopted, still retained its original pronunciation /ɣ/, so that k would be the Germanic sound nearest to the Latin g . In all the Germanic languages the word was ultimately refashioned after Latin, with change of k into g ; hence Old English *Grécas* plural beside *Crécas*.

In Old English, "Crecas"/"Grecas" is attested only as a plural.  The singular appears in the Middle English period.

In 15th and 16th centuries the words "German", "Italian" and "Russian" were introduced based on Latin models.

The words "Chinese" and "Japanese" were taken from French in the Early Modern English period, and the word "Portuguese" was borrowed from Portuguese around the same time.  Originally the word "Chineses" was used as a plural, according to the OED:

> The plural *Chineses* was in regular use during 17th cent.: since it became obsolete *Chinese* has been singular and plural; in modern times a singular *Chinee* has arisen in vulgar use in U.S. (So sailors say *Maltee*, *Portuguee*.)

Comment: And if we're hungry enough, we can refer to "the danish" (sg.)!

Answer (score 3):

It has to do with forming plurals. The plural of French and Chinese doesn't change as it makes for awkward pronunciation; same with Spanish. In contrast it easy to form the plural of Greek and German by simple adding 's'.

I believe you can generalize this by the word's ending but I'm not sure if this would cover all cases or if there would still be exceptions.

Comment: If "the French" is a plural noun, what is it the plural of? "A French"?  That doesn't really work. I think the structure is more like "the poor" or "the rich", "the strong" or "the weak": an adjective interpreted as plural.

Comment: I do not quite get your point. You can't just say "A French." You can say "The French..." which would be inherently plural or "A French person..." if you wanted to refer to one in general. As for adjectives, I see what you are saying but it still doesn't answer the discrepancies as noted in the original question.

Comment: Oh, I was just nitpicking about your wording "The plural of French and Chinese **doesn't change**"—this doesn't make much sense to me because, change from what? There is no "singular" noun that "the French" could be compared to. There is an adjective "French", but I would say that English adjectives don't have plural forms or singular forms, not that they have plural forms that don't change compared to the singular forms.

Comment: Ok, I see what you are saying now. Good point. This is something I will need to think about further. :)

Comment: _"They seek him here, they seek him there; those -"_ No wait, never mind me.

Comment: Sumelic, you've appreciated the essence of my question. Ryan, you have a decent point but see sumelic's. Mr Lister, you confuse me. Please explain if you will.

Comment: @J.Doe Sorry, didn't mean to confuse you. Just wanted to point out that some people, under some circumstances, could refer to the French as _"Frenchies"_. Shall I delete my comment?